# In my code, you can set a score for 1 test, but I need for three tests

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to modify my code . So that the user enters the number of students and their grades on three tests, and the program writes to him how many students have entered the institute (passing score = 7, maximum score = 10). I wrote the code for one test and don't know how to write for three.
This problem is under the comment: "//Information input and calculation"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Attestation {
    
    
    

    static double InputNumber(String caption) {
        System.out.print(caption);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            
        boolean IsError;
        do {
            IsError = !sc.hasNextDouble();
            if (IsError) {
                System.out.print("ERROR: ");
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        } while (IsError);
        
        return sc.nextDouble();
    }
                
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
    // Entering quantities of numbers
        int count = (int) InputNumber("enter the number of students: ");
        
    // Header
        System.out.println("Test №1\t │ Test №2\t │ Test №3");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");

    // Information input and calculation
        int passed = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i = i + 1) {
            double number = InputNumber("enter the grades of the " + i + " student: ");
        if(number >= 7) {
        passed = passed + 1;
            
        }
            
    }
        
    // Displaying information
            System.out.println("---");
            System.out.println(passed + " students entered the institute");
            
            
        }

    }
```

I tried to modify the code, but I was constantly getting an error

Comment: Inside your existing for loop, you add another for loop that asks for three numbers.  After you receive the three numbers, you average them (I guess) to get the final score, where you check for passing.  You only need to declare one instance of `Scanner` in your `main` method and pass that instance to your `inputNumber` method.  Method names start with a lowercase character.  Variable names start with a lowercase character.